For an arbitrary convex 3d figure, when the *surface area* is determined, can we know the range of the *volume*?
For an arbitrary convex 3d figure, when the surface area is determined, can we know the range of the volume? In other words, the maximum and the minimum volume of the figure?
What about the opposite? Is it possible to know the range of the surface area for a given volume?
For example, consider a rectangular prism whose length, width, and height are $a$, $b$, and $c$, respectively, and let its volume $V$ fixed. Let its surface area be $A$.
$$V=abc,\ A=2ab+2bc+2ca$$
By AM-GM inequality,
$$\dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{3}\geq abc^{2/3}$$
$$2ab+2bc+2ca\geq 6abc^{2/3}=6V^{2/3}$$
The equality holds if and only if $a=b=c$, therefore for the surface area to be the minimum, the length, width, an height of the prism should the same, i.e. a cube.
P.S. I'm 15 years old and don't know a bunch of things in mathematics including calculus. Thus, it would be appreciated if you could give me some intuition, in the case the answer is too difficult for me. Thanks in advance!

Split the given surface area into two congruent $2d$ shapes (say disks) and leave a little left to have very small height. Then build a cylinder. It is convex and has arbitrary small volume. Can you proceed?

@KurtG. What does "arbitrary small volume" mean?

@SineoftheTime Gabriel's horn does not look convex to me.

@justdoingmaths . That means if you tell me a very small volume (your choice) I can construct you the cylinder that has at most that volume.

Among all bodies with given surface area, a sphere has the largest volume. This is a special case of  isoperimetric inequality in 3-dimension.

@KurtG. oh, I did not see the word "convex".

@KurtG. Is it using "disk" and building "cylinder" that I should focus on? Let the radius and height of the cylinder be $r$ and $h$, respectively. $A=2\pi r(r+h)$ is constant, so $r(r+h)=k$ is also a constant. $h=k/r-r,\ V=\pi r^2 h=\pi r^2(k/r-r)=\pi r(k-r^2)$ Should I find out the maximum of the function $y=\pi x(k-x^2)$?

$\pi x(k-x^2)>0,\ -x^3+kx>0,\ -x^2+k>0,\ x^2<k,\ -\sqrt{k}<x<\sqrt{k}$
so, for $0<x<\sqrt{k}$, $y>0$
I think for a cylinder, there is no maximum or minimum but it feels like there are some kind of upper and lower limit for $y$
$k=A/(2\pi )$, so $0<x<\sqrt{A/(2\pi )}$

@achillehui Is there a way that I can understand this in an intuitive way?

The cylinder can be used to show that the minimum volume of a convex body with given surface area is zero. The maximum volume was addressed by @achillehui's comment.

@KurtG. Oh, I got it. The radius of the sphere that has the surface area of $A$ is $\sqrt{\frac{A}{4\pi}}$, and the volume is \frac{A}{3}\sqrt{\frac{A}{4\pi}}, which means the range for the volume is
$0\leq V\leq \frac{A}{3}\sqrt{\frac{A}{4\pi}}$.
Thanks!
